# django-registration Email Customizations

Tags: django, django-registration

I am using django-registration, and have two questions with regards to customizing the email sent after a user has requested to reset his password.

This is what I currently have in `password_reset_email.html`:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% blocktrans %} Please click the link below to change your password:
{% endblocktrans %}

{% block reset_link %}{{ domain }}{% url auth_password_reset_confirm uidb36=uid, token=token %}

Thanks,
Mysite
{% endblock %}
```

And in my `settings.py`:

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'Mysite'
```

I have two questions --

1) Currently the email is from `Mysite`, with return address `'Mysite'`. How do I make it so it appears as `Mysite`, but the return address is `'Mysite@no-reply.com'`?

2) Currently the subject of the email says `'Password reset on Mysite'`How/where do I change the subject of the reset-password email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You should change your email setting to `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'Mysite <Mysite@no-reply.com>'`

2) The last I checked, this was not changeable. django-registration has the subject line hardcoded.

**EDIT:**
Correction: The password reset subject line is set by Django's `PasswordResetForm`not django-registration.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the subject of the email in your <...>templates/registration/activation_email_subject.txt

Make sure that file exists, then put in it whatever you want.

Also, your email should be "no-reply@mysite.com" instead of mysite@no-replay.com.